# Read file into HashMap Java

Tags: java, file, hashmap

I'm trying to read lines from file into Arraylist. Here is my writer  :

```
private Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> motPage = 
                                             new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();

private void writer() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException, IOException{

  try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(
                          new OutputStreamWriter(
                             new FileOutputStream("/home/kdiri/workJuno/motorRecherche/src/kemal.txt"), "utf-8"))) {
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : motPage.entrySet()){
      writer.write(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue() + "\n");
    }
  }
}
```

And this is an exemple result in the file kemal.txt :

```
0 : [38, 38, 38, 38, 199, 199, 199, 199, 3004, 3004, 3004, 3004, 23, 23]
```

My question is how can I read it these lines efficiently into Hashmap again ? Because size of file is about 500MB. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far, and what happened? I would strongly advise you to get something working first, *then* worry about whether or not it's efficient. The main task is going to be parsing a line of data into a key and a value (which is itself a list of integers). That can be done without reference to a map, and without reference to a file...

Comment: Try to avoid it if possible. It would be much more efficient to work only with piece of data at the time (like streams in javaIO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JonSkeet said, you should start with something working. Find below one possible way. The snippet is kept quite verbose to show the principle.

```
String line = "0 : [38, 38, 38, 38, 199, 199, 199, 199, 3004, 3004, 3004, 3004, 
    23, 23]";

int firstSpace = line.indexOf(" ");
int leftSquareBracket = line.indexOf("[");
int rightSquareBracket = line.indexOf("]");

String keyString = line.substring(0, firstSpace);        
String[] valuesString = line.substring(leftSquareBracket + 1, rightSquareBracket)
    .split(", ");

int key = new Integer(keyString);
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(valuesString.length);
for (String value : valuesString) {
    values.add(new Integer(value));
}

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> motPage = new HashMap<>();
motPage.put(key, values);
```

Btw. `read ... these lines efficiently into Hashmap` depends on your requirements. Efficiency could be for example:

- read speed of the huge file
- convertion speed String to Integer
- small size of the bytecode
- less object generation
- ... there could be other as well

When the snippet does not fulfil your `efficiency` criteria. Start to tune the part which impacts your criteria.

Comment: Thank you for your advices and it's work. I used String.split() functiun to parse lines everytime, when I use it, I had to wait a lot to parse txt file. But now, with your codes it works well.